# CASE logic in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, min

```
 CASE when Min(P.ID) then p.addressline1 

 CASE when P.ID=Min(P.ID) then p.addressline1
```

Are the above two case statements same? If not, why?

Comment: Those statements don't make sense without context - you need to show the entire query.

Answer (score 1):

This statement doesn't evaluate against anything...

```
CASE when Min(P.ID) then p.addressline1
```

But the second does. You'd need something like

```
CASE when Min(P.ID) > 5 then p.addressline1
```

For it to be valid.